# Vertical gaps present on iOS app but not on Unity editor

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, tiled

Using Unity2D 2017.1.1f1, Tiled and Tiled2Unity, I exported a tiled map in Unity and there are no problems in the editor. I also tried it played maximised and there are no gaps present.

[image: Screenshot from Mac]

The problem shows up when the game is ran in iOS specifically iPhone 6s. There are noticeable gaps showing up.

[image: Screenshot from iOS]

Also, I also got the settings like this:

[image: Screenshot from settings]

Any suggestions? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm the Tiled2Unity author)

Those gaps you are seeing are seams and they're common in Unity development when using tile or sprite sheets that "touch" each other. There are a number of ways that you can [fix them described here](https://tiled2unity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fixing-seams/).

However, these seams are fixed automatically [with SuperTiled2Unity](https://seanba.itch.io/supertiled2unity) which is still free (or name your price) and is currently under soft release. Just be aware that all your Tiled files (TMX, TSX, textures) will need to be in Unity now (that's a good thing). 
Dragging in all your files (with relative paths intact) to Unity should take care of the importing process for you.

Comment: thanks for the info, didn't expect that this app is still alive :)